# Android rxJava2 project structure, file naming, etc

Tags: java, android, rx-android, rx-java2

I have an Android project that currently doesn't use View Models or rxJava.  It's a fairly straightforward app that uses the Parse sdk with a parse-server.  It's still early in the project and I've decided to start using VM and rxJava.

My question is mostly about structure, naming etc.  Let's use Login for an example:

I have an interface called`AuthenticationService.java` with a `login(Authorization auth, ServiceCallback<User> callback)` method.

My `ParseAuthenticationService.java` implements that interface and does all the parse stuff.

The whole app is set up like that, so my `User.java` is an interface used by `MyParseUser.java` where all the parse stuff happens.

So there's a login button, `LoginActivity` grabs the username/password, makes an Authorization object and calls the login function.

**Is the change to rxJava as simple as wrapping the `login` function in an observable and subscribing to it in the activity?**

**What would that look like?**  The login function looks like this:

```
@Override
public void login(Authorization authorization, final ServiceCallback<User> callback)
{
    cachedUser = null;
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(authorization.getUsername(), authorization.getPassword(), new LogInCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e)
        {
            if (callback != null)
            {
                callback.onServiceRequestComplete(Response.<User>from((MyParseUser) user, e));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Can I keep the same Parse-class-using-generic-interface structure?**  Or should I restructure/rename my files?

Thanks for any help.  This is all a bit overwhelming.

Answer (score 0):

Using interface separate contract declaration from implementation. Since the Observable pattern is a nice way to represent asynchronous responses, replacing callback with Observables in your interfaces seems a good fit.

You could begin to put Observable version of your callback function alongside. For example, writing an `Observable<User> loginObservable(Authorization auth)` (or better `Single<User> loginSingle(Authorization auth)`) that essentially wrap `login( ... )` with `Observable.create()` or `Single.create()`. You may need a refactoring afterward, but you will do it when you familiar with Rx. For me switching to Rx was a 2 steps process; I evolved my architecture but a lot later.

Since creating Observable like this is a little advanced Rx topic, I would recommend you to look for already existing Rx wrappers for Parse.